# select directory + extract exif using python

Tags: python, directory, exif

I would like to have a folder full of photographs and use python to scan the directory and list the exif information in the following format:

Image001
Exif Data

Image002
Exif Data

I'm going to be using Tkinter to create a GUI from python, so I'm just wondering what commands i'll need to:

1) Select a directory e.g Desktop etc
2) Extract exif information

I should be able to create a text file which will hold the exif information.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/28/getting-photo-metadata-exif-using-python/ should help you with reading EXIF-data from images. Uses the Python Imaging Library (PIL).

For listing files in a directory, `os.listdir(directory)` will get you a list of files AND subdirectories.

Something like

```
files=[os.path.join(directory, f) for f in os.listdir(directory) 
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(directory, f))] #Get only files, not directories
for f in files:
  #open file, do EXIF stuff
```

should get you started